# Excel VBA: Copy cells from specific workbook in loop to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am writing a macro. The purpose is to iterate through a list of spreadsheets (I have two sets saved in the same directory and each set has a specific naming convention). One set is named as "GenLU_xx" and the other is named as "LUZ_Summary_xx". The 'xx' in each name refers to a name e.g. Calgary. So I would have two different spreadsheets for Calgary (LUZ_Summary_Calgary & GenLU_Calgary).

The Macro needs to open each spreadsheet starting with "LUZ" add a value to G1. I have accomplished this first part by modifying code I found here: http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder
The macro asks the user to identify the directory the spreadsheets are stored in and then loops through ones starting with "LUZ*".
The code is:

```
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "LUZ*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & myFile)

    'Add GEN_LU_ZN to column G1
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("G1").Value = "GEN_LU_ZN"



    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I need for it to do from this point is copy two specific columns from each of the spreadsheets starting with "GenLU" and paste them into sheet 2 of the corresponding spreadsheet.

For example column C & E need to be copied from "GenLU_Calgary_2008" to the second sheet in the corresponding spreadsheet "LUZ_Summary_Calgary_2015". The code needs to somehow match up the spreadsheets using the name (in this case Calgary) and it needs to do this for all the spreadsheets.

Sorry for the extremely long question, but I'm hoping some can help a VBA newb out. I've searched quite a bit and while I have found the code to copy from sheet to sheet or workbook to workbook I am having trouble achieving what I need to. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to test something without having any files, but you can try the following as part of your code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim MyAr() As String: MyAr = Split("Calgary,XXX,YYY", ",")

For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)

    Do While myFile <> ""
        If myFile Like "GenLU" & "*" & MyAr(i) Then
            Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Do While myFile <> ""
        If myFile Like "LUZ_Summary" & "*" & MyAr(i) And Not wb1 Is Nothing Then
            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
            wb2.Worksheets(1).Columns(3).Value = wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns(3).Value
            wb2.Worksheets(1).Columns(5).Value = wb1.Worksheets(1).Columns(5).Value
            wb1.Close
            wb2.Save
            wb2.Close
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Set wb1 = Nothing

Next i
```

Note that you did not provide information which Worksheet you are working on, so I assume its always `Worksheets(1)`. Column C = `Columns(3)`. `MyAr()` is a String array to store the countries.

Comment: Thanks EDC, I'm going to test it out and comment here. Much appreciated!

Comment: @gistech007 Would you comment what doesn't work for you, or if everything is fine, feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Hi EDC, Sorry I haven't been able to check if your code works yet. Once I get the chance to I definitely will.

Comment: @gistech007 dude its about time time to make your decision. You got helped here for free and you do not seem to value this at all, which is simply BM.

Comment: Hey EDC. I apologize for not replying but I've had stuff going on. Also decided to not go the vba route. Thanks for your help though.